# How to show $\mathbb{Z} + \alpha \mathbb{Z}$ not closed for irrational $\alpha$?

Tags: general-topology

My textbook say this set is OBVIOUSLY dense in $\mathbb{R}$ and not closed, but I don’t get it. How to show it is dense and not closed?

Comment: It's not obvious.  The idea is to work by contradiction.  Suppose it is not dense, deduce that this means there is a least positive element $x$ and use that to conclude that $\alpha $ is rational, thereby obtaining the desired contradiction.

Comment: And once you know that it's dense, you know it's not closed, because a dense closed set is the entire space. But this set is countable, so it can't be all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Somehow the OP asked for showing that it is not "closed". This can be shown once we know it's dense: if it's closed, then it is equal to the whole $\mathbb R$ by density. But the set is obviously countable while $\mathbb R$ is not countable.